# Volume of arithmetic quotients of symmetric spaces

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemannian-geometry, algebraic-groups, symmetric-spaces, arithmetic-groups

Now let $\textbf{G}$ be some connected semisimple linear algebraic group over a number field $F$. Let $G_{\infty}$ be $\textbf{G}(\mathbb{R}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} F)$.  Let $K_{\infty}$ be a maximal compact subgroup of $G_{\infty}$. We fix an embedding $G\hookrightarrow GL_N$ for some $N$. Let   $\mathfrak{P}$ denote a prime of $\mathcal{O}_F$ lying over $p$. Let $G(\mathfrak{P})$ be the intersection of $G_{\infty}$ with the congruence subgroup of $GL_N(\mathcal{O}_F)$ at level $\mathfrak{P}$. Let $\Gamma$ be an arithmetic lattice of $G_{\infty}$.
     Let us denote
        $\Gamma (\mathfrak{P}):=\Gamma \cap G(\mathfrak{P})$.
    Let us denote by $e$ and $f$ the ramification and inertia degrees of $\mathfrak{P}$ in $F$. Hence we get that $[F_{\mathfrak{P}}:\mathbb{Q}_p]=ef$ where $F_{\mathfrak{P}}$ is the completion of $F$ at $\mathfrak{P}$.  We define $G_k:=G \cap (1+p^kM_{efN}(\mathbb{Z}_p))$ where $G:=\varprojlim_k\Gamma /\Gamma({\mathfrak{P}}^k)$ 
     For $k\geqslant 0$, we define $Y_k:=\Gamma (\mathfrak{P}^{ek})\backslash G_{\infty} /K_{\infty}$.

Then let $vol(\mathfrak{P}^{ek})$ be the volume of $\Gamma(\mathfrak{P}^{ek})\backslash G_{\infty}$.

Let $\Gamma(\mathfrak{P}^{ek})\backslash G_{\infty}$ be compact.

Then I want to show that $vol(\mathfrak{P}^{ek})\sim [G:G_k]$. Here $\sim$ denotes that both of them are similar order as $k \rightarrow \infty$. It will be helpful if I can get some hints or some reference on this fact. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by the amount of notation, but look at the canonical map from $\Gamma(\mathfrak P^{ek})\backslash G_\infty$ to $\Gamma\backslash G_\infty$. It should be a (possibly ramified) covering of degree $[G:G_k]$, and this should imply your claim.

Comment: @ACL: I understand that the covering map $\Gamma(\mathfrak{P}^{ek})\backslash G_{\infty}$ to $\Gamma \backslash G_{\infty}$ has deck transformation group $G/G_k$. But how does it imply the statement on volume?   I see the following: We can cover $\Gamma\backslash G_{\infty}$ by finitely many open balls whose pullback by the covering map covers $\Gamma(\mathfrak{P}^{ek})\backslash G_{\infty}$ and $vol$( $\Gamma(\mathfrak{P}^{ek})\backslash G_{\infty}$) is then bounded by $[G:G_k]\cdot vol(\Gamma\backslash G_{\infty})$. But how to prove that they are $\sim$, i.e 'similar ' not just bounded.

Comment: The deck transformation group preserves the measure. See Paul Garrett's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a unimodular topological group $G$, and for discrete subgroups $\Theta\subset\Gamma\subset G$, for $f\in C^o_c(\Theta\backslash G)$, it is true that
$$
\int_{\Theta\backslash G} f \;=\; \int_{\Gamma\backslash G}\sum_{\gamma \in \Theta\backslash\Gamma} f\circ \gamma
$$
in the sense that choice of right $G$-invariant measure on one quotient uniquely determines the right $G$-invariant measure on the other. This follows from the surjectivity of the obvious averaging map from compactly-supported continuous functions on the one quotient to the other.

Comment: @garrett: Thanks for the explanation